# Getting the User Email from Microsoft 365 OAuth2 for IMAP

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, microsoft365

I want to use the Microsoft 365 OAuth2 to authenticate and authorize users in a multi-tenant environment for IMAP/SMTP access using the scope:

```
openid profile email offline_access https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send
```

The issue is I need to make separate calls to get the access tokens related to exchange and another for getting the email of the user using the Graph scope.

This makes a complicated logic for a web-based access where you will need to get two separate auth code and separate access tokens to get the user email address and the imap/smtp access token.

I need both to make a auth call to access Imap/Smtp e.g.

```
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (Username, AccessToken);
```

Instead of making two calls, I was wondering if I got the id-token from the exchange scope (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`) and use optional claim for the user email address, will that be an acceptable way to get the user email? Is this email always available?

Otherwise is there a better way to do this (rather than getting two sets of access tokens)?